# Changing the year in several files

Tags: regex, sed

I'm trying to use sed to update the date in a bunch of files.

Here's a list over how the copyright section might look

```
Copyright 2015
CopyRight 2012, 2015 
copyright 2011-2012 
CopyRight   2014
```

I want to change it to

```
Copyright 2015
```

or

```
CopyRight 2011-2015
```

This is what I have so far

```
sed -i 's/copyright[\s]*(2015)?([0-9]*).*//I'
```

The problem is using the capures in the substitution. I would like to do something in the lines of "if group 1 is a match, do nothing, if group 2 matches, substitute with \2-2015"

Comment: could you post the expected output for all the four lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for the example listed, the following seem to match the expected result:

```
sed 's/\(copyright.*\)201[01234]$/\12015/Ig'
```

The expression match each line of copyright that does not end with 2015, if you have copyright that run since 200. or even 19.. you'll have to adapt this regex.

BTW, to try this, just forget the -i switch of sed

Comment: There's one thing it won't get: "Copyright    2011-2012" will update the year, but not fix the extra whitespace. Perfect fix would be "Copyright 2011-2015"

Comment: @Q-bertsuit: just make a second pass -with a second expression (-e) to sed, no need for a pipe here- to change ', 2015' to '-2015'. Not the most efficient but will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you want to

- replace `word word Copyright xxxx word` with `word word Copyright 2015 word`;
- replace `word word Copyright xxxx<date_separator>yyyy word` with `word word Copyright xxxx<date_separator>2015 word`.

This needs a "does not match" condition, which is a bit awkward to do in `sed`, so instead of a one-liner this text transformation is best written as a `sed` script.

```
#!/usr/bin/sed -f
/copyright\s\+\([0-9]\{4\}[, -]\+\)[0-9]\{4\}/I{
    s/copyright\s\+\([0-9]\{4\}[, -]\+\)[0-9]\{4\}/Copyright \12015/i;
};
/copyright\s\+\([0-9]\{4\}[, -]\+\)[0-9]\{4\}/I!{
    s/copyright\s\+[0-9]\{4\}/Copyright 2015/i;
}
```